# app crashing only on SOME phones (when connecting to internet?)

Tags: android, http, crash

I'm the only one who can successfully upload image from gallery to app online... for others, the phone seems to crash upon http requests, it appears. Is this on my end or their end? thanks..

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

super.onCreate(icicle);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),

R.drawable.icon2);

Bitmap bitmapOrgg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BrowsePicture.selectedImagePath);

ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

//bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);

bitmapOrgg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 30, bao);

byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();

String ba1=Base64.encodeBytes(ba);

ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new

ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",ba1));

try{

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost httppost = new

HttpPost("http://asdfasdf.php");

httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

is = entity.getContent();

}catch(Exception e){

Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
Log.d("1","1");
}



try{
    Class ourClass = Class.forName("www.xxx.com");
    Intent ourIntent = new Intent(upload.this, ourClass);
    startActivity(ourIntent);
    Log.d("2","2");
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

This is an example of when it crashes. However, it also crashes in another instance. I believe it's when they are using parts of the app that connect ot the internet.

It works on my phone, but it has not worked on anyone elses (I have an S1 Blaze, they've had Nexus and Galaxy S4)

Update:

```
try{
    Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.x.x.asdf.");
    Intent ourIntent = new Intent(upload.this, ourClass);
    startActivity(ourIntent);
    Log.d("2","2");
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    loadSomeStuff uploader= new loadSomeStuff();
    // since the first param in <Void,Void,Void> you do not send in anything in execute.
    uploader.execute("test");

    Log.e("LOG", BrowsePicture.selectedImagePath);



}


public class loadSomeStuff extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),



                R.drawable.icon2);

                Bitmap bitmapOrgg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BrowsePicture.selectedImagePath);
                Log.e(BrowsePicture.selectedImagePath, "yo");
                ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                //bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);

                bitmapOrgg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 30, bao);

                byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();

                String ba1=Base64.encodeBytes(ba);

                ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new

                ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",ba1));

                try{

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpPost httppost = new

                HttpPost("http://website.com/php");

                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                is = entity.getContent();

                }catch(Exception e){

                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
                Log.d("1","1");
                }
        return "test";
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String pinny){

    }
}


}
```

Comment: cmon pls.. post your logcat output

Comment: Try to set your timeout higher.. ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making network calls on the main UI thread.

This might be working on your phone because you have a old android version (I'm guessing Gingerbread).

Starting from API level 11, this would throw a [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

**Solution:**
Network calls should only be made from a background thread.

I suggest using an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). [Example](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html)

Comment: thanks for the help. I tried it, and it seems that all it's doing is having their phones crash a bit later, or just after the failure of the connection or something... some updated code:

Comment: If you are still having the same problem please post your error log. You can find it in the LogCat view.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, I know. But what was happening was that the newer phones were taking higher quality pictures, and during the upload process, I guess the size of the images were too large. so I had to reduce them beforehand.

BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opts.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

```
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BrowsePicture.selectedImagePath, opts);
    int width = opts.outWidth;
    int height = opts.outHeight;

    opts.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    opts.inDither = true;
    opts.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    opts.inSampleSize = (int)Math.pow(2.0,Math.floor(Math.log(2)/Math.log(2)));//for example double scale_factor=(double)width/desired_dimension;

    Bitmap bitmapOrgg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BrowsePicture.selectedImagePath,opts);
```